# Whare are general knowledge you should learn before (Java Developer) inteview?

Tags: java

You are applying for a role "Java Developer" and you are called for an interview.
What are the general knowledge you should/must learn before you sit in front of the panel?

Comment: That question is waay too general.  What do you count as "general knowledge"?  American History?  Expansionary cosmology?

Comment: The amount of knowledge you'll be expected to have will depend on the nature of position offered. If it says "at least 2 years commercial experience", then a lot more will be expected than for a fresh graduate. So there's no simple answer to your question. But definitely know Java to SCJP level.

Comment: general knowledge = common.
Anything that you as candidate get asked all the time, some people don't experience much at the interview whereas some have attended to lots of interviews, and there might be someone out here is the interviewer who could give one or two good tips (not everything)

Answer (score 2):

I would read the [Sun Certified Java Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072253606) study guide.  Many employers don't expect you to have the actual certification, but they do expect you to know the material (whether they explicitly say so or not).

Comment: agree with you. it's handy when it come to technical session.

Comment: Agree completely.  If it is a general Java deleloper position, the guide is basically the Bible

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of interviews for java postions I've been in, design patterns have been a big topic.  Specifically Factory/Abstract Factory/Singleton/Facade.  Doesn't hurt to brush up on those.

Answer (score 1):

I've interviewed a couple of developers in the past, as well as joined a couple of interviews.  What I've seen so far:

- Design Patterns - Which ones have you used, and why.
- Collection classes
- Threading
- Memory usage

For some places that want to dig a little further:

- Soft and weak pointers
- Java I/O classes
- Profiling
- Debugging

Depending on the position, then come specifics like usage of frameworks in case of a web developer, or Eclipse RCP, or Swing, whatever is the required technology for the job.  In that case it is relatively difficult to generalize.  My bet is that a little Swing never hurts.

Comment: Thank you Mario. We need more tip from Interviewer. No need to be specific but a clue of what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well first and foremost you need to be proficient in Java and be comfortable talking about coding problems which may be presented to you during the interview. Knowledge of (the curent state of) some frameworks is also a nice plus. Usually java is used on server side stuff, so try to look into some Spring, Wicket, Tapestry, Struts, JSP, JSF, Ibatis, Hibernate, or other interesting stuff.

Also, having a fallback plan to go into "presentation mode" if the interviewers do not seem to have interesting questions for you is a good plan. You want to show your stuff. Wow them, without lying.

Be careful with wat you say, some interviewers might actually have more experience than you, but do not show it, until it is verdict time.

Good luck with your interviews.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on position you are applying for.
In java most commonly asked questions are on

1. Threads
2. Serialization : Specially serialversionUUID once interviewer had also asked me about default algorithm to calculate serialversionUUID.
3. Collections: In and outs of collections Hashset, LinkedList, DeQueue, Iterator etc
4. Basic Oops concepts. Questions like diff between abstraction and polymorphism etc
5. Markup interface, immutable classes, reflection(rarely)

Second part of interview will be on design patterns
Commonly asked design patterns are

1. Singleton Pros- cons
2. Factory vs Dependency injection
3. Builder
4. Decorator vs Dependency injection
5. Command
6. Strategy
7. Visitor

Logical questions are always based on algorithms and I will advise to have knowledge of most of searching sorting algorithms as this is the base of software engg.

Answer (score -1):

A few good tips here. At least you tell someone where to start.